# static method create inner class with generic

Tags: java, generics

It is a demo about inner class and generic type.

```
    class OuterClass<T> {

    public OuterClass() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OuterClass<String>().new InnerAbstractClass() {
        };
    }

    public class InnerAbstractClass {
        T t;
        public void a() {

        }

    }
}
class OuterClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(1);
        new OuterClass<String>().new InnerAbstractClass() {

        };
    }
}
```

Though it is compiled successfully, there is error info in main of OuterClass while no error in main of OuterClassTest.
[image]
I wonder why it is inconsistency.
I'm using jdk8 and the newest IDEA.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: [This code works fine](http://ideone.com/8oRSVW). If there's an error, it hasn't "compiled successfully"; but I can't replicate this error.

Comment: Why did you name the non-abstract class `InnerAbstractClass`?

Answer (score 1):

The code works. It even compiles (also in IntelliJ). The IDE just shows an error. Try to execute your inner main class and this will work. 
Maybe you could open up an issue for JetBrains at
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FIDEA

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like any warning like this, you could try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OuterClass<String> outerClass = new OuterClass<String>();
    outerClass.getInstance();
}

public InnerAbstractClass getInstance() {
    return new InnerAbstractClass();
}
```

Comment: The name given was `OuterClass`, not `OutterClass`. As a rule the name parts should have conventional spelling.

Comment: Sorry it is just a mistake. But it works, and suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Since InnerAbstractionClass is not using any non-static members of OuterClass, you could just make InnerAbstractionClass static to get rid of this error.
P.S. - This error has nothing to do with generics.